# violated - parent key not found error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this 2 tables in my database,DEPT1 and EMP1 wich referes to the department of employers and the list of employers,the table EMP1 contains a foreign key named refdept.
[image]
my problem is that I can insert data to DEPT1 but not to EMP1,this is what I get as exception:

```
instanciation de la connexion connexion1
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:12 PM tp.dao.DeptDAO create
Infos:  create new instance
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.DeptDAO create
Infos: New instance is created.
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.DeptDAO create
Infos: Return Result == true
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.EmpDAO create
Infos:  create new instance
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.EmpDAO create
Grave: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BASE.FK_DEPT) violated - parent key not found

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (base.FK_DEPT) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
l'employéEMP5est ajouté à cet département
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1007)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at tp.dao.EmpDAO.create(EmpDAO.java:48)
    at tp.TP.main(TP2.java:84)
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.EmpDAO create
Infos: Return Result == false
nov. 17, 2014 7:54:13 PM tp.dao.EmpDAO create
Infos: Return Result == false
```

I tried this :

```
insert into base.EMP1(ide,nome,rue,ville,refdept) values (7,"EMP5","agadir","dddd",(select idd from base.DEPT1 where nomd ='Math'));
```

I get this error:

```
Error code 984, SQL state 42000: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

any help pleaze and thanks :(

Comment: the error is because you are violating the referential integrity, you can not insert values in a column with foreign key, if this values does not exists in parent table

Comment: thanks Aramillo for your reply,how can I add values to the refdept then??

Comment: add missing record(s) to DEPT1 table

Comment: can you explain more @Aishu and thanks :)

Comment: in picture you post, you can only insert into refdept column values 1,2,3 an 4 because they are the only values presents in dept1.id column

Comment: `"EMP5"` is a column name, not a string literal: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BASE.FK_DEPT) violated - parent key not found

There is no such a value in DEPT1, please check it first.

> insert into base.EMP1(ide,nome,rue,ville,refdept) values (7,"EMP5","agadir","dddd",(select idd from base.DEPT1 where nomd ='Math'));

Try this:

```
insert into base.EMP1(ide,nome,rue,ville,refdept)
select 7,'EMP5','agadir','dddd', idd from base.DEPT1 where nomd ='Math';
```

Comment: thanks Mr Tim Nanos I tried the syntax in my code,but now I have another error java.sql.SQLException: Index de colonne non valide

Comment: Pay attention to what you inserting, make sure those are correct values. Run the query in SQL Developer and you'll see more information about the error.

Comment: @Lina Check that, if `ide` column is a primary key, you can't use an `insert as select` because you are inserting value `7` many times, that's may be the cause of error

Comment: Should I create a sequence for each table and a trigger for insertion?

Comment: @Lina Sequence is needed for a unique value (if ide should be unique - then yes). And as for trigger - it depends on business logic behind the code, I think it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you dont have **idd** column in DEPT1

try:

```
insert into base.EMP1(ide,nome,rue,ville,refdept) values (7,"EMP5","agadir","dddd",(select ido from base.DEPT1 where nomd ='Math'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try it like this:

```
insert into base.EMP1(ide,nome,rue,ville,refdept) values (7,'EMP5','agadir','dddd',
(select idd from base.DEPT1 where nomd ='Math'));
```